# Вылет кастомных настроек при их открытии

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, добавлял тут в свои настройки Battery light, но вот не задача, вылет получаю...

```
09-05 08:52:36.552   946   956 I zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 93035(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 11(760KB) LOS objects, 42% free, 10MB/18MB, paused 1.492ms total 153.260ms
09-05 08:52:36.666   946  2200 E LightsService: Light requested not available on this device. 2
09-05 08:52:36.776   946  3114 I ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x8000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$OctogenSettingsActivity (has extras)} from uid 1000
09-05 08:52:36.878  7631  7631 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.settings, PID: 7631
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$OctogenSettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.preference.Preference.onPrepareForRemoval()' on a null object reference
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.preference.Preference.onPrepareForRemoval()' on a null object reference
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceGroup.removePreferenceInt(PreferenceGroup.java:220)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceGroup.removePreference(PreferenceGroup.java:213)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.octogen.settings.OctogenSettings.onCreate(OctogenSettings.java:51)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2593)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2415)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2194)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2148)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2049)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:798)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.switchToFragment(SettingsActivity.java:768)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.launchSettingFragment(SettingsActivity.java:432)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:345)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
09-05 08:52:36.879  7631  7631 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
09-05 08:52:36.884   946  3900 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings$OctogenSettingsActivity
09-05 08:52:36.890   946  3900 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings
09-05 08:52:36.894   946   963 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.android.settings u0
09-05 08:52:36.939   946  3179 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-05 08:52:36.939   946  3179 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
09-05 08:52:37.388   946   962 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{d0acb0a u0 com.android.settings/.Settings$OctogenSettingsActivity t105 f}
09-05 08:52:37.995  3971  4054 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
```

Вот мой порт коммита с другого репозитория:

https://github.com/OctoDev-Project/octogen_packages_apps_OctogenSettings/commit/bf69b82570239723b1fe15311920f405cc227c25